# Is it proper to specify the interaction term between two independent continuous variables of model A) as the dependent variable in a second model B)?

Tags: interaction, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

**1. Main problem**

I am struggling with a mediation – moderation question. Is it proper to specify the interaction term between two independent continuous variables of model A) as the dependent variable in a second model B)? If yes, what does the final specification look like?

Model A): Y = a0 + a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + a4(x1*x3) + error_A

Model B): x1*x3 = b0 + b1x2 + error_B

**2. Aim of the model**

I would like to answer the question, how the variable x2 influences the moderation process (interaction term) in model A.

Specifying it as a three-way interaction instead (Y = a0 + a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + a4(x1*x3) + a5(x1*x2) + a6(x2*x3) + a7(x1*x2*x3) + error) doesn't seem right, because there is a strong relationship between x2 and at least one of the variables, which are part of the interaction term (x1 and x3).

I read through the material provided by [Andrew Hayes](http://www.processmacro.org/papers.html), but apparently non of the templates (he offers wonderful templates as part of his PROCESS macro for SPSS to do moderation analyses) suites my needs.

**3. Additional considerations**

I guess what I conceptually need, is the mediation model which results when I combine Model A) and B):

Model C): Y = a0 + a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + a4(b0 + b1x2 + error_B) + error_A

Moreover, since I expect x2 to influence the interplay of x1 and x3, I guess I need to incorporate the influences of x2 on x1 and x3 as well.

Model D): x1 = d0 + d1x2 + error_D

Model E): x3 = e0 + e1x2 + error_E

Model F): Y = a0 + a1(d0 + d1x2 + error_D) + a2x2 + a3(e0 + e1x2 + error_E) + a4(b0 + b1x2 + error_B) + error_A

**4. How I would go about it**

Basically, all I would technically do is specify four regression models (Model A, Model B, Model D and Model E) and then summarize the coefficients, such that the change in Y as a result of a one step increase in x2 can be expressed as: a1*d1*x2 + a2*x2 + a3*e1*x2 + a4*b1*x2.

So, how about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do want a 3-way interaction. The interpretation of the coefficient of the 3-way interaction is the change in the effect of the interaction between x1 and x3 corresponding to a change in x2, which is exactly the quantity you seem to want to estimate. You can also see how x2 affects Y in this model. You can also do correlation analysis to show the relationship between x2 and x1, and between x2 and x3.